# ggplot2: How to dynamically specify faceting variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

Let's say I have a dataframe with a column `facet` that I want to use for faceting. Easy:

```
ggplot(...) + facet_grid(. ~ facet)
```

But I want to dynamically specify the faceting column like so:

```
FACET_COLUMN <- 'facet'
ggplot(...) + facet_grid(. ~ FACET_COLUMN) # of course doesn't work
```

How does that work? I'm basically looking for a faceting equivalent to `aes_string()`.

Comment: `Target <- “facet”; fac_var <- df[[Target]]; ggplot(…)+facet_grid(fac_var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `get` the variable in `facet_grid`.

Using the built-in `diamonds` dataset as example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

FACET_COLUMN <- "color"

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ get(FACET_COLUMN))
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and logical. Funny I never used get() before, it's a very basic function.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach by [the vignette](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function) is to use the `.data` pronoun.

```r
library(ggplot2)

FACET_COLUMN <- "cyl"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(.data[[FACET_COLUMN]]))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-07 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>